# method not found for Mandrill ruby gem -- cut and pasting from example

Tags: ruby, methods, mandrill

I am using the same code as found in the Mandrill documents:

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23257181-Using-the-Mandrill-Ruby-Gem

I cut and paste and get the following error at this line:

```
m = Mandrill::API.new =>
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mandrill-0.0.4/lib/mandrill/api.rb:35:in `initialize'
```

But this is exactly as described in the official docs.

When I, on my own, pass a parameter for the environment variable as follows:

```
m = Mandrill::API.new(ENV['MANDRILL_APIKEY'])
```

I get a legitimate client.  However, the next line fails:

```
sending = m.messages.send message

DEBUG -- : HTTPI POST request to mandrillapp.com (excon)
Mandrill::API::Error: (-99) Unknown method "..messages"
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/mandrill-0.0.4/lib/mandrill/api.rb:51:in `method_missing'
```

Seems like things aren't working.  This set of code worked prior.  But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you're not using the official gem called `mandrill-api` but rather a deprecated 3rd party gem called `mandrill`. Use the former and the problem should go away.

Comment: Post a little more context around that code snippet.

Comment: First you should try `gem uninstall mandrill`. Are you sure you're running rails console or whatever you're using with `bundle exec ..` at the beginning? If it won't help, ensure that you don't have that third party `mandrill` gem in your Gemfile.